# How to determine the size of subfolders in a directory using java?

Tags: java

I have a directory having a lot of sub folders in it. How can I determine the size of every sub folder and file present in it using java?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(File f)` method in the commons.io [library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html).